# Powershell Script not picking up latest revision

Tags: powershell, sorting, automation, archive

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
param(
    [STRING]$path = $PSScriptRoot
)

# Set the source and destination folders
# $srcFolder = "COPY PATH OF PDF FILES"
$srcFolder = $path
$destFolder = "$srcFolder\Latest Drawings"



# Get all files in the source folder that match the pattern
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcFolder -Filter "*_*.*" -File
foreach ($fileName in $files.Name) {
    $name = $fileName.split('_')[0]
    
    $latestRevisionNo = 0
    $revisions = $files.Name | Where-Object { $_ -like ("{0}*") -f $name }
    foreach ($revision in $revisions) {
        $revision = $revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
        if ($revision -gt $latestRevisionNo) {
            $latestRevisionNo = $revision
        }
    }

    # Copy Latest revision
    if (-not (Test-Path -path $destFolder)) {
        New-Item -path $destFolder -ItemType Directory
    }

    $latestRevision = $files.Name | Where-Object { $_ -like ("{0}_{1}.pdf") -f $name, $latestRevisionNo }
    Copy-Item -Path ("{0}\{1}" -f $srcFolder, $latestRevision) -Destination $destFolder -Force
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

The code posted here works for the most part. But with a few issues and kinks I can't figure out where double digits appear to be the problem and are not picked up when the script is being run.

Our files are formatted like the testing/troubleshooting files below.

I format a bulk of files formatted as reflected, with drawing #_Revision #.pdf I was hoping to develop a script to have a folder with the latest versions. based on the value between the _ and .

**Trouble Shooting Results**

ex: AE1.101A_1.pdf, AE1.101A_2.pdf, AE1.101A_3.pdf, AE1.101A_4.pdf, AE1.101A_25.pdf

picks up AE1.101A_4.pdf, not AE1.101A_25.pdf

ex: GI0-503_REL 35.pdf, GI0-503_REL 36.pdf, GI0-503_REL 41.pdf

picks up GI0-503_REL 41.pdf

ex: AE1.101A_1.pdf, AE1.101A_2.pdf, AE1.101A_3.pdf, AE1.101A_4.pdf, AE1.101A_400.pdf

picks up AE1.101A_400.pdf

ex: GI0-503_REL 35.pdf, GI0-503_REL 36.pdf, GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, GI0-503_REL 410.pdf

picks up GI0-503_REL 410.pdf

ex: GI0-503_REL 35.pdf, GI0-503_REL 36.pdf, GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, GI0-503_REL 210.pdf

picks up GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, not GI0-503_REL 210.pdf

ex: AE1.101A_1.pdf, AE1.101A_2.pdf, AE1.101A_3.pdf, AE1.101A_4.pdf, AE1.101A_10.pdf

picks up AE1.101A_10.pdf

Ex: GI0-503_REL 35.pdf, GI0-503_REL 36.pdf, GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, GI0-503_REL 310.pdf

picks up GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, not GI0-503_REL 310.pdf

Comment: *…picks up `GI0-503_REL 41.pdf`, not `GI0-503_REL 210.pdf`* because in `if ($revision -gt $latestRevisionNo)` you are comparing strings `'REL 210' -gt 'REL 41'` *lexically* -> `False`

Comment: Problem is you are treating numbers as string so '4' is later than '13' because the '4' > '1'.

Comment: @JosefZ I see your point but if that is indeed correct, I dont know how the code gives me this result below. 

ex: GI0-503_REL 35.pdf, GI0-503_REL 36.pdf, GI0-503_REL 41.pdf, GI0-503_REL 410.pdf

picks up GI0-503_REL 410.pdf

Comment: `$revision = [int]$revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]`. (perhaps use a better iterating variable name in that foreach like `$fileName` perhaps?)

Comment: @ZacharyAlexander - the number suffixes in your comment *just happen* to sort the same numerically *and* as strings - 35 < 36 < 41 < 410 *and* “35” < “36” < “41” < “410”. Try adding “GI0-503_REL 99.pdf” to that file list and watch where it sorts (hint - it’ll appear at the end because the *string* values compare as “410” < “99” - the first character “4” < “9”).

Comment: Note that Windows Explorer does some clever things to detect number sequences in file names so if you look at them there you’d correctly see 35, 36, 41, 99, 410, but PowerShell just uses “dictionary” or “character” sort order so “410” comes before “99”. If you want *your* code to correctly handle number sequences you’ll have to write the code yourself - for example @theo’s suggestion.

Comment: REPLACING: $revision = $revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]

With @Theo suggestion: $revision = [int]$revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]   ? It doesnt work or gave me errors upon running the code.

Comment: Your code ```$revision = $revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]``` is *still* doing string comparison - "4" vs "25", so "4" is greater. Theo's example has ```[int]``` prefixing the expression, so ```$revision = [int]$revision.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]``` which converts the strings to integers and compares 4 vs 25 and 25 is greater.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on all the comments, when you perform *string* comparison it performs a dictionary-style character-by-character comparison.

E.g.:

- `a` < `b` < `ba` < `c`
- `1` < `2` < `21` < `3`

This means that *strings* with consecutive digits in them *don't* sort numerically - they sort according to the position of the characters in the string.

For example:

- `AE1.101A_25.pdf` < `AE1.101A_4.pdf`

because the two strings differ at character 10 and `2` < `4` so `AE1.101A_25.pdf` < `AE1.101A_4.pdf` as well.

If you want consecutive digits in a string to be sorted *numerically* you've got to do some extra work to extract the values yourself so you can compare them as *numbers* not *characters*.

@Theo gave you the answer in the comments as follows:

```
$names = @(
    "AE1.101A_1.pdf",
    "AE1.101A_2.pdf",
    "AE1.101A_3.pdf",
    "AE1.101A_4.pdf",
    "AE1.101A_25.pdf"
);

$latestRevisionNo = 0;
foreach( $name in $names )
{
    # $name = "AE1.101A_4.pdf"  -> [int] "4"  -> $revision =  4
    # $name = "AE1.101A_25.pdf" -> [int] "25" -> $revision = 25
    $revision = [int] $name.Split("_")[1].Split(".")[0];
    if ($revision -gt $latestRevisionNo)
    {
        $latestRevisionNo = $revision;
    }
}
write-host "latest revision = $latestRevisionNo";
```

The key is to convert the trailing digits into a number with `[int]` and then you can do *numeric* comparison rather than *string* comparison, and as a result the output from the above is:

```
latest revision = 25
```

### Update

The reason some of your examples fail with the above code is that you're not actually isolating the numeric part of the filename in all cases.

For example this works fine:

```
PS> "AE1.101A_25.pdf".split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
25

PS> [int]("AE1.101A_25.pdf".split('_')[1].split('.')[0])
25
```

but this fails:

```
PS> "GI0-503_REL 35.pdf".split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
REL 35

PS> [int]("GI0-503_REL 35.pdf".split('_')[1].split('.')[0])
Cannot convert value "REL 35" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

To fix *this* problem you'll need to update the way you extract the numeric part of the filename so it works on all filenames. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...